# Making a login Using JavaScript, Will Incorporate PHP Later

Tags: javascript, web, authentication, scripting

not sure why my code wont work, im teaching myself javascript i know php moderatly and i also know the intelligence of using java to hold a password and username, but at the moment i just want the script to work.

```
<html>
  <head>

    <title>34webs</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>

    <script type="javascript" >

    function logintry (){

    var usern = document.logn.username.value;
    var passw = document.logn.password.value;

    if(usern == blue && passw == bluee){


    alert('password is correct!');

    }else{

    alert('password is wrong');

    }



    }


    </script>

      </head>

      <body>

    <div id="bod">

      <div id="nav">
        <p id="buttonhead">34 web</p>
        <a href="#" class="button">HOME</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">NEWS</a>     
        <a href="#" class="button">DOWNLOADS</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">ERA</a>  
        <a href="#" class="button">IE BROWSER</a>
        <a href="#" class="button">DRIVERS</a>      

        <form name="logn">
        <table style="margin:0 auto; background:#0174DF; color:white;">
        <tr>
        <td>
        Username<br>
        <input type="text"
               name="username"
               value="">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        Password<br>
        <input type="password"
               name="password"
               value="">        
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="button"
               name="Submit"
               value="submit"
               onclick= javascript: logintry()>         
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>



        </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: Asking your question entirely in capital letters makes it seem like you're shouting. It's considered rude. Please don't do it.

Comment: I love this: http://bash.org/?835030 :)

Comment: might think about not using all caps, IT SOUNDS ANGRY!

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite catch that, could you speak up a bit?

Comment: Just an FYI, storing or passing sensitive information in JavaScript is a HUGE security flaw. Everyone can view your source and see it.

Comment: --author-- : sorry about the caps, i use a data management system that requires caps. so i always forget to change. dont mean to be rude.

Comment: @TIMOTHY: Do you also live in the 80s? I remember they had a lot of computers where non-capital letters weren't supported properly.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen lol its a DMS buddy, i didnt make the program, i only use it. so leave your jokes at the door and try to help me.

Comment: @TIMOTHY: Is it... a DMS from the 80s?

Comment: more than likely, its a car dealership DMS. they are not the best programmers on the block. but it is a solid program. its all command prompt. no mouse functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a comparison to a variable name, not a string.  Change it to

```
if( usern == "blue" && pw =="bluee"){
  //do stuff
}
```

**Edit** After you comment, I took another look at your code, you need to surround the `javascript: logintry()` call with quotes.  You are correct in using onclick.  You need to remove the "javascript:" That is the syntax when you are using href.  Onclick will automatically call the script and doesn't need the protocol prefix.

Comment: Yes it does help, it however might not have solved all the problems your script has.

Comment: oo okay, i saw in another program that the line didnt have the quotes. i thought it was suppose to, well that didnt help either, but as long as you think its a working form then i guess i can just debugg it. but what do you mean onclick handler? isnt that what i did?

Comment: and i know it helped matt, i just mean it didnt solve the problem im having.

Comment: @TIMOTHY you're right, you were. sorry I read it quickly and when I saw javascript: My mind filled in href rather than onclick. Apologies.

Comment: alright, thank you very much for your help. hopefully i can figure this out. youve given me a good push. ive checked the thing let me know if i need to do anything else to give you a score for the answer.